# My IP blocked after uploading data from WinSCP

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to import and upload the data in Azure VM using Azure portal and WinSCp.

After few hours my IP is blocked and I am unable access a Azure portal using below URL

portal.azure.com and manager.windowsazure.com

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Contact Azure support. If your IP is really blocked, its because you triggered some sort of security heuristic.  They're the only ones that can help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Azure support is probably the only way you can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure never blocks IP addresses on such bases. What most likely is the cause for the issue, is the issues Microsoft is fighting the whole day - Azure had some DNS and network outages few hours ago. Still some issues: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/